# How to permanently install GLUT for visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2015, glut

Is there anyway to permanently install GLUT for visual studio 2015? I tried searching for it and it has showed some steps to add the GLUT libs and dlls in the project. Well this way does work but as far as I've noticed I have to do all the steps all over again if I create a new project and do code in that which is definitely not efficient. So is there anyway to permanently include GLUT  files in visual studio 2015?

Comment: Create a VS library project with all the necessary files.  When you create a new application project just include the above library project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a property sheet in your vs, then fill out the libs, dlls and include path and save it, you can import it next time when you create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but I'm going to share what worked for me.

1. Download the pre-compiled GLUT binaries from [here](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glutdlls37beta.zip) and extract it anywhere you want
2. Find and `cd` into your VS 2015 path, for me it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC`
3. From extracted GLUT folder copy all *.lib files to `lib` folder on your path, all *.h files to your `include` folder and *.dll to `bin` folder

Now your Visual Studio 2015 project should recognize when you add GLUT `include`s.